# Upgrading the twitter bootstrap gem from 2.x to 3.x or 4.x is breaking the UI styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am trying to upgrade the `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem version from `2.2.8 version to 3.2.2 version` since 2.2.8 has vulnerabilities.

But while upgrading the gem version it is breaking the UI styles everywhere in the application nav-bar, search, and modal box, etc.

I followed the steps given in the [official documentation](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) 
by running this command `rails generate bootstrap:install less` after doing the `bundle install.`

Is there any other configurations that we need to change other than this? I thought it will be a simple gem upgrade but not sure where things are going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the GetBoostrap documentation (the successor of "Twitter Bootstrap) and should install the

```
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.5.0'
```

The migration guide is here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/migration/

Comment: I added the gem as suggested, but it's throwing the following error `ExecJS::RubyRacerRuntime is not supported. Please replace therubyracer with mini_racer in your Gemfile or use Node.js as ExecJS runtime.` I need the rubyracer gem so even If I try to replace it with mini_racer, it's throwing an error `activesupport-6.0.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in require: cannot load such file -- v8 (LoadError)`

Comment: And also what you are suggesting is changing from twitter-bootstrap-rails gem to bootstrap. This involves moving from less to sass. And we try to keep them in less itself. So I believe this is different from what I am expecting.

Comment: You 're right I thought going to bootstrap might be the best choice.

Comment: Yeah, that would be right. But I would like to stick with `twitter-bootstrap-rails` for now. Thanks for your suggestion though :)